# Keeping the size of ldf file under certain limit

Tags: sql-server

I have scenario where ldf file on SQL Server grew to more than 30GB in course of 4-5 days. As this presents potential problem with space (the HDD is a bit more than 250GB) I searched few solutions but came baffled as anything that I find on shrinking of ldf file says that it will grew again. One solution is to periodically perform this operation but I am not sure if it will be helpful in long term. Is it possible somehow to fixate maximum size of ldf file and then olders records in it would removed automatically by SQL Server?

If this doesn't sound good please do share some ideas on how should I manage this? What is the best course of action?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look into **Transaction Log Backups!**

Comment: What recovery model is the database in?

Comment: One is in Simple, another one is in Full.

Comment: Which LDF file grew to 30GB? In any event see [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two scenarios with this situation.

Scenario 1 - database is in simple recovery and there is a large process growing the transaction log. In this case, there's not much you can but leave the transaction log at the largest size and upgrade your drive space if possible.

Scenario 2 (most likely) - Your database is in full recovery mode and you don't have transaction log backups configured. A good backup practice is a daily full backup (if your database isn't too big) and an hourly transaction log backup. After you have a good full backup followed by a good transaction log backup you can shrink the transaction log.

Here's some code that may help:

**Shrink Transaction Log -** [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (LogicalLogName, SizeInMB)
```

**How much of the transaction log is being used -**

```
USE DatabaseName
GO

DBCC SQLPERF (logspace)
```

If you find that after you shrink the transaction log that the file size is the same, try to adjust the file size manually in the transaction log settings. Alternatively, you can set the database to simple recovery and then back to full recovery. Although the latter will break your transaction log backups until the next full backup.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was going to do something similar. My idea is to put logs in simple recovery mode, then shrink them and limit the maximum size of the file on disk.

My additional question is would that pose some long-term issue? I must add to this discussion that the DB itself is used only as a middleware, the data that were inserted in this database are processed by another application and stored on entirely different system which is maintained by experts so data are safe there.

Comment: So it sounds like the data doesn't need to be backed up frequently. I think your plan is good. However, keep in mind that even though the database is in simple mode, transactions are still being written to the transaction log. If you have one large process that occurs, it won't write a checkpoint until the process is complete. The tlog will not truncate until a checkpoint has been written. For example, if I write a query to delete 1 million rows it will write out all 1 million rows to the transaction log before a checkpoint occurs even in simple mode.

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. As far as I know there's no such large transaction occurring on these databases so I don't see potential problem for now. However, I tried to assume how much it will pose a problem if such big transaction gets executed and set pretty high limit for log files.

Additional question is, can I somehow calculate or at least get vague approximation how much space a transaction will take? I presume there's no easy formula.

Comment: Your are right, there is no easy formula. It all depends on the process. What I usually do is set my log size and the allow it to autogrow if needed. After a month or so if you haven't seen your log size grow then you should be good. If it does grow then just leave it at whatever size it grows too. One thing you don't want to do is let it grow, shrink it, let it grow, shrink it. This causes fragmentation and degrades performance.